# Find file name from full file path

Tags: file, r, path

Is there a way to extract the file name from the file full path (part of a file path) without the hassle of manipulating string?

The equivalent in Java would be:

```
File f = new File ("C:/some_dir/a")
f.getName() //output a
f.getFullAbsolutePath() //output c:/some_dir/a
```

Answer (score 380, accepted):

Use

```
basename("C:/some_dir/a.ext")
# [1] "a.ext"
dirname("C:/some_dir/a.ext")
# [1] "C:/some_dir"
```

Comment: I knew about `basename()`, but then I forgot. These functions should be mentioned in the "See also" section of the [list.files](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.files.html) and [file.path](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/file.path.html) help pages.

Comment: Yes. I search google and stumble upon this answer about once a week.

Comment: how about extracting the basename without the extension? is that a native function as well?

Comment: @PaulRougieux I submitted a feature request, and this should be included in an upcoming R release :)

Answer (score 25):

The *tidyverse* equivalent lives in the [fs](https://fs.r-lib.org/) package. {fs} makes use of [libuv](https://libuv.org/) under the hood.

```r
library("fs")

path_file("/some/path/to/file.xyz")
#> [1] "file.xyz"

path_dir("/some/path/to/file.xyz")
#> [1] "/some/path/to"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.  Just used this code to set names for a list column, which was incredibly tedious without path_file()

Answer (score 3):

@Honeybear.
The function that removes the extension from the filename you could use is the function from the {tools} R package

```
tools::file_path_sans_ext("ABCD.csv")
## [1] "ABCD"
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29114021/5417978) in SO

Answer (score 1):

While trying to find the [fastest method to extract a filename from a path in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72356498/what-is-the-fastest-method-to-extract-the-file-name-from-a-path-in-r/) I found that using `sub` with the regex `".*/"` was ~an order of magnitude faster than `basename` (if speed is an issue).

```r
files<-paste0("http://some/ppath/to/som/cool/file/",1:1000,".flac")

sub(".*/", "", files,perl = T)
```