# Define the file path from the file name in R

Tags: r, macos, file, path

I know that I can [find file name from full file path in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548815/find-file-name-from-full-file-path-in-r), but is there a way to define the path to the file just from the file name? Think about such scenario: you store the data file in the cloud (e.g. Dropbox) so the path for this file is slightly different at your home:  `read.table("path/user1/data.dat")` and work: `read.table("path/user2/data.dat")`. Therefore, every time you want to `read.table()` you have to change one element of the path to match either you work or home path (on Mac OS X it's specifically the `User` part of the path that you need to change). I was wondering whether it's possible to make R to automatically detect such change in the path (e.g. different `User`) or detect the path to the file just from the name of this file.

Comment: Not really an answer, but the path to a home directory can be set as `"~/"`. In Windows this seems to path to `user\documents` which by default holds the dropbox folder and in linux to `user` which by default holds the dropbox folder. So for dropbox `read.table("~/Dropbox/...")` should work, I think. Should also work for Mac (as that is Unix).

Comment: @Sasha No, it won't work on Mac. Dropbox is held within `/Users/username/Dropbox/...`.

Comment: Yeah and `"~/"` should link to `/Users/username/` on Mac and Linux, not `/users`. sorry about that.

Comment: You're much better off learning how to use working directories than messing with fragile automated solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the environment variables with `Sys.getenv()`.

Here is a short extract from the results on my machine:

```
Sys.getenv()

...
USERNAME 
"Andrie" 
USERPROFILE 
"C:\\Users\\Andrie" 
windir 
"C:\\Windows"
```

You can extract individual elements by including the name of that element in the call:

```
> Sys.getenv("USERNAME")
[1] "Andrie"
```

---

If you can identify in these variables exactly what it is you need, you can then construct your file path using `file.path`

---

For more information on the environment variables, and some system-specific exceptions, see `?Sys.getenv`

Comment: excellent, thank you. On Mac this element in `Sys.getenv()` is either `USER` or `LOGNAME`.