# accessing individual values split by str_split in R, finding the last one?

Tags: string, r

This should be dead simple, but I can't figure it out.  I have a string that represents a path name to a file, ie

"C:/blah/this/whatever/filename"

And I need to extract the filename (programatically).  I am trying to use strsplit (or str_split) and, it is easy enough to split the string by '/' but.. I cannot fathom how to actually extract one of the values in the returned vector, or determine how many elements are even in the vector (as that may very for my application).  Using length (oddly enough, to my mind) does not help.  Help?

Comment: The question should be retitled to be less generic, it is blocking solutions to the more generic question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken from: [Find file name from full file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548815/find-file-name-from-full-file-path)

```
basename("C:/some_dir/a")
> [1]  "a"

dirname("C:/some_dir/a")
>[1] "C:/some_dir"
```

Although I think the above approach is much better, you can also use the `str_split` approach - which I really only mention to show how to select the last elements from a list using `lapply`.

```
example <- c("C:/some_dir/a","C:/some_dir/sdfs/a","C:/some_dir/asdf/asdf/a")
example.split <- strsplit(example,"/")
files <- unlist(lapply(example.split, tail , 1 ))
```

Comment: Thanks!!!  For reasons I won't go into, I cannot use the first approach (should have mentioned that I tried it), but the lapply approach does work for my application.  Thank you, dayne.

Answer (score 4):

Don't need str_split:

```
sub( "^.+/(.+)$", "\\1",  "C:/blah/this/whatever/filename" )
```