# Get filename without extension in R

Tags: r, r-faq

I have a file:

```
ABCD.csv
```

The length before the `.csv` is not fixed and vary in any length.

How can I extract the portion before the `.csv`?

Answer (score 213, accepted):

There's a built in `file_path_sans_ext` from the standard install **tools** package that grabs the file without the extension.

```
tools::file_path_sans_ext("ABCD.csv")
## [1] "ABCD"
```

Comment: Anyone looking for more details on this and similar functions, take a look at `?tools::file_ext`

Comment: After tested, I think it's better to put file path in `basename()` as `file_path_sans_ext(basename(filepath))`.

Answer (score 53):

`basename` will also remove the path leading to the file. And with this regex, any extension will be removed.

```
filepath <- "d:/Some Dir/ABCD.csv"
sub(pattern = "(.*)\\..*$", replacement = "\\1", basename(filepath))

# [1] "ABCD"
```

Or, using `file_path_sans_ext` as Tyler Rinker suggested:

```
file_path_sans_ext(basename(filepath))

# [1] "ABCD"
```

Comment: Special case: a file having "several extensions", like "ABCD.txt.csv" (yeah, it happens), then just add a '?' to make the expression non-greedy: `sub(pattern = "(.*?)\\..*$", replacement = "\\1", basename(filepath))`

Answer (score 30):

You can use `sub` or `substr`

```
sub('\\.csv$', '', str1) 
#[1] "ABCD"
```

or

```
substr(str1, 1, nchar(str1)-4)
#[1] "ABCD"
```

Using the 'file_path' from @JasonV's post

```
sub('\\..*$', '', basename(filepath))
#[1] "ABCD"
```

Or

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(filepath,  perl('(?<=[/])([^/]+)(?=\\.[^.]+)'))
#[1] "ABCD"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- 'ABCD.csv'
```

Comment: Yes, it would remove too.  Why do you need the `.` after the `\\.` Could that be also a `.` literally i.e. `foo..`

Comment: You are right of course, this was a typo. My bad. Now I cannot edit this anymore.

Comment: How about this: sub('\\.[^\\.]*$', '', "foo.txt")? This will remove the very last extension.

Comment: @stephanmg  There could be  edge cases like `foo.` Not sure what to do with those

Comment: Yes, I'd assume this is not sound input. Before applying your command, one could check this (Or even, we could modify the regex?)

Comment: @stephanmgI would say that regex would be more custom case i.e. it cannot be applied to all the general cases.  Suppose if the OP mentioin that he/she will only have `.<word>` at the end and there are no other cases, this would work

Comment: Okay, I think this is fine then.

Answer (score 11):

[`fs::path_ext_remove()`](https://fs.r-lib.org/reference/path_file.html) "removes the last extension and returns the rest of the path".

```r
fs::path_ext_remove(c("ABCD.csv", "foo.bar.baz.txt", "d:/Some Dir/ABCD.csv"))

# Produces: [1] "ABCD"             "foo.bar.baz"      "D:/Some Dir/ABCD"
```

Answer (score 7):

If you have filenames with multiple (possible extensions) and you want to strip off only the last extension, you can try the following.

Consider the filename `foo.bar.baz.txt` this

```
sub('\\..[^\\.]*$', '', "foo.bar.baz.txt")
```

will leave you with `foo.bar.baz`.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this also:

```
data <- "ABCD.csv"
gsub(pattern = "\\.csv$", "", data)

#[1] "ABCD"
```

This will be helpful in case of list of files as well, say

`data <- list.files(pattern="\\.csv$")` , using the code will remove extension of all the files in the list.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an implementation that works for compression and multiple files:

```
remove.file_ext <- function(path, basename = FALSE) {
  out <- c()
  for (p in path) {
    fext <- file_ext(path)
    compressions <- c("gzip", "gz", "bgz", "zip")
    areCompressed <- fext %in% compressions
    if (areCompressed) {
      ext <- file_ext(file_path_sans_ext(path, compression = FALSE))
      regex <- paste0("*\\.",ext,"\\.", fext,"$")
    } else {
      regex <- paste0("*\\.",fext,"$")
    }
    new <- gsub(pattern = regex, "", path)
    out <- c(out, new)
  }
  return(ifelse(basename, basename(out), out))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Loading the library needed :

```
> library(stringr)
```

Extracting all the matches from the regex:

```
> str_match("ABCD.csv", "(.*)\\..*$")
     [,1]       [,2]  
[1,] "ABCD.csv" "ABCD"
```

Returning only the second part of the result, which corresponds to the group matching the file name:

```
> str_match("ABCD.csv", "(.*)\\..*$")[,2]
[1] "ABCD"
```

EDIT for @U-10-Forward:

It is basically the same principle as the other answer. Just that I found this solution more robust.

Regex wise it means:

- () = group
- .* = any single character except the newline character any number of time
- // is escape notation, thus //. means literally "."
- .* = any characters any number of time again
- $ means should be at the end of the input string

The logic is then that it will return the group preceding a "." followed by a group of characters at the end of the string (which equals the file extension in this case).

Answer (score 2):

The above answers are great, but I was interested in which was fastest for dealing with millions of paths at once.  It seems that using `sub` via [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72356498/what-is-the-fastest-method-to-extract-the-file-name-from-a-path-in-r/) is the fastest for getting the filename out of the path.  and then comparing three of the methods above, using `tools::file_path_sans_ext` is faster.

```r
library(fs)
library(stringr)
library(microbenchmark)

files<-paste0("http://some/ppath/to/som/cool/file/",1:1000,".flac")

microbenchmark(
    fs::path_ext_remove(sub(".*/", "", files)),
    tools::file_path_sans_ext(sub(".*/", "", files)),
    str_extract(files,  '(?<=[/])([^/]+)(?=\\.[^.]+)')
    
)
```

```
Unit: milliseconds
                                                expr     min       lq      mean   median      uq     max neval
          fs::path_ext_remove(sub(".*/", "", files)) 10.6273 10.98940 11.323063 11.20500 11.4992 14.5834   100
    tools::file_path_sans_ext(sub(".*/", "", files))  1.3717  1.44260  1.532092  1.48560  1.5588  2.4806   100
 str_extract(files, "(?<=[/])([^/]+)(?=\\\\.[^.]+)")  7.4197  7.62875  7.985206  7.88835  8.2311  9.4107   100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substring()`

```
filename <- "test_channels.csv"
only.extension <- substring(filename,nchar(filename) - 3 )
without_ext.name <- substring(filename,1, nchar(filename) - 4 )

# verify
only.extension
without_ext.name
```

I hope it will be helpful.