# How to extract the last text after forward slash

Tags: r

I have a df that looks like this:

| AF | GT | Sample_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.001 | 1/1 | path/to/sample/name/ID0001.vcf.gz |
| 0.005 | 0/1 | path/to/sample/name/ID0002.vcf.gz |

What I want is to only keep the ID name in the Sample_name column:

| AF | GT | Sample_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.001 | 1/1 | ID0001 |
| 0.005 | 0/1 | ID0002 |

I would very much appreciate any help in achieving this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29113973/get-filename-without-extension-in-r

Answer (score 3):

There are some built in file name helpers that you can use here.

- `basename()`
- `tools::file_path_sans_ext()`

So in this example simply do:

```r
library(tools)

df$Sample_name <- file_path_sans_ext(basename(df$Sample_name), compression = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex pattern with `gsub()`:

```
gsub(".*(ID\\d*).*", replacement = "\\1", x = "path/to/sample/name/ID0001.vcf.gz")
#> "ID0001"
```

Across your dataframe:

```
df$sample_name2 <- gsub(".*(ID\\d*).*", replacement = "\\1", x = df$sample_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is tidyverse solution. Note this only works if you ID string has always: ID followed by 4 numbers:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Sample_name=str_extract(Sample_name, 'ID\\d{4}'))
```

```
    AF  GT Sample_name
1 0.001 1/1      ID0001
2 0.005 0/1      ID0002
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sub` with `basename` to take the sample name:

```
df$Sample_name <- sub('\\..*$', '', basename(df$Sample_name))
df
```

Output:

```
     AF  GT Sample_name
1 0.001 1/1      ID0001
2 0.005 0/1      ID0002
```

#### Data

```
df <- data.frame(AF = c(0.001, 0.005),
                 GT = c("1/1", "0/1"),
                 Sample_name = c("path/to/sample/name/ID0001.vcf.gz", "path/to/sample/name/ID0002.vcf.gz"))
```