Regex: match shortest pattern between two possible delimiters
I am struggling with a regex. I use R for my example, but any compatible regex is welcome.
Here is the problem: consider this exemple:
test <- c("truc/truc/plouf.xlsx","plouf.xlsx","truc/plouf.xlsx")


I would like to have plouf extracted each time.
I tried:
library(stringr)
str_extract(test,"(?<=\\/{0,1}).+(?=\\.xlsx)") 


Which gives me

[1] "truc/truc/plouf" "plouf"           "truc/plouf"

I naively though that using a lazy .+? in str_extract(test,"(?<=\\/{0,1}).+?(?=\\.xlsx)")  would solve the problem, but it does not.
How should I do ?

Are you always trying to get a filename without an extension? If so rather than regex use the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29113973/get-filename-without-extension-in-r e.g. in your case tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(test))

@SamR but this give the path anyway. I woul like to only have the filename without extensions

Are you using basename()? That should strip the path

To extract the terminal filename (having an extension) you should be OK using:
library(stringr)

test <- c("truc/truc/plouf.xlsx", "plouf.xlsx", "truc/plouf.xlsx")
files <- str_extract(test, "[^/]+(?=\\.\\w+$)")
files

[1] "plouf" "plouf" "plouf"

The regex pattern here says to match:

[^/]+ match any one or more characters, but not slash
(?=\\.\\w+$) until looking ahead and seeing the file extension (but don't match it)

