# R subset file name between characters (Not Full Path)

Tags: r, string, subset

I would like to subset file names only from folders. So from name like below,

```
"C:/Users/UserName/Document/Folder1/Foder2/Data_2020_12_15_Test Set.docx"
"C:/Users/UserName/Document/Folder1/Foder2/Doc_2020_08_12_Test Set.docx"
```

How to subset strings after backslash to docx, and apply it to a list in order to get output as below?

```
 Data_2020_12_15_Test Set.docx
 Doc_2020_08_12_Test Set.docx
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find file name from full file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548815/find-file-name-from-full-file-path)

Comment: I 'm not searching for full file path but subset file names from full path.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this is exactly what ```basename()``` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this over the vector with the strings containing the filenames:

```
#Data
val <- c('C:/Users/UserName/Document/Folder1/Foder2/Data_2020_12_15_Test Set.docx')
#Code
gsub('^(?:[^/]*/)*\\s*(.*)', '\\1', val)
```

Output:

```
[1] "Data_2020_12_15_Test Set.docx"
```