# Extract list of files with column of files names in R

Tags: r, extract

I am trying to extract the name and properties of files in a folder. I am using the code below, which works well, except that it does not extract the file name in a column. The first column has the full path to the file, but is there a way to get the file name with extension (eg file1.pdf) in a separate column?

```
data_files <- file.info(list.files(path = choose.folder(), 
    full.names = T, recursive = T, pattern = ".pdf$", ignore.case = TRUE))
```

Update: I was told about this question which is similar: [Find file name from full file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548815/find-file-name-from-full-file-path)

which is similar but I still prefer the answers below as they are more detailed and explained the steps in more details.

Comment: Try with `basename`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
data_files$filename = basename(rownames(data_files))
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this works. If you know of any articles describing more r commands to work with file lists, please send the link to benefit from. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `basename` directly on the `list.files`

```
basename(list.files(path = choose.folder(), 
    full.names = T, recursive = T, pattern = ".pdf$", ignore.case = TRUE))
```